# Contacts section overlaps the section that uses display: grid above it

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a problem that I encountered while I was trying to coding a landing page. 
Basically I have this two sections, expertises and contacts.
The problem is that the section contacts overlaps the section above it on small screens. 
In the expertises section I have a container where I put a display: grid in order to align all the elements correctly.
Everything works fine on big screens though.
Do you have any idea about how could I fix this problem?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jry2kmaq/)

HTML:

```
   !<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--expertise-->
    <section id="expertises">
      .<div class="container">
        <div class="expertises-head">
          <h2>Di cosa mi occupo</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="expertise1">
          <img src="./img/together.png">
          <h3>Competenza 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="expertise2">
          <img src="./img/together.png">
          <h3>Competenza 2</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="expertise3">
          <img src="./img/together.png">
          <h3>Competenza 3</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="expertise4">
          <img src="./img/together.png">
          <h3>Competenza 4</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="expertise5">
          <img src="./img/together.png">
          <h3>Competenza 5</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="expertise6">
          <img src="./img/together.png">
          <h3>Competenza 6</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--END expertise-->

    <!--contacts-->
    <section id="contacts">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="contacts-head">
          <h2>Contatti</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="contacts-form">
          <form action="contattami.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="InputName">Nome e cognome</label>
              <input type="text" name="nome" required="" placeholder="Nome e cognome" class="InputName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="InputEmail">Indirizzo e-mail</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" required="" placeholder="Indirizzo e-mail" class="InputEmail">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="InputSubject">Oggetto</label>
              <input type="text" name="oggetto" required="" placeholder="Oggetto" class="InputSubject">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="InputMsg">Messaggio </label>
              <textarea name="messaggio" rows="4" required="" placeholder="Messaggio" class="InputMsg"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" placeholder="Invia" class="Submit">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-others">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="contact-email">
                <h3 class="text-uppercase">Indirizzo email <img src=".\img\mail.png"></h3>
                <p>probootstrap@gmail.com</p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="contact-cellphone">
                <h3 class="text-uppercase">Cellullare <img src=".\img\smartphone-call.png"></h3>
                <p>+30 976 1382 9921</p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="contact-skype">
                <h3 class="text-uppercase">Skype <img src=".\img\skype-logo.png"></h3>
                <p>Maria.rosaria.ciullo</p>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="contact-address">
                <h3 class="text-uppercase">Indirizzo <img src=".\img\location.png"></h3>
                <p>San Francisco, CA</p>
                <p>4th Floor8 Lower</p>
                <p>San Francisco street, M1 50F</p>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--END contacts-->

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}

img{
  width: 100%
}

.container{
  max-width: 1271px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 3rem;
}



/* expertises */
#expertises{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 5em 0;
}

#expertises .container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

#expertises .expertises-head{
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 1;
  margin-bottom: 2vh;
}

#expertises img{
  width: auto;
}

/* contacts */
#contacts{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 5em 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#contacts .container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

#contacts .contacts-head{
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

#contacts .contacts-form{
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 2;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(72,94,116,0.7)
}

#contacts .contact-others{
  grid-column: 3/3;
  grid-row: 2;
  text-align: left;
}

#contacts .contact-email, .contact-cellphone, .contact-address, .contacts-skype{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#contacts .text-uppercase{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#contacts ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

#contacts p{
  line-height: 8px;
}

#contacts img{
  width: auto;
}
```

This is the problem basically.
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Using your demo in Chrome, there is no overlap between "Di cosa mi occupo" & "Contatti" sections on smaller screens.

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer. Well, I assure that there is a problem as you can see in the new picture I posted. That screen comes from the original file though.

Comment: I would like to assist you, but I don't see the problem you describe in the code you provided. Try to post enough code to reproduce the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a media query for width below 600px and change `#contacts .contact-others` class with the following it should work.

```
#contacts .contact-others{
   grid-column: 1/3;
   grid-row: 4;
   text-align: left;
}
```